# Command not found when publlshing branch through my VSCode

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, repository, branch, publish

Image shows "command not found" when I click on publish branch on my VSCode:

[image]

I opened terminal and it says problem is not been detected with this file

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact situation a few minutes ago, although I had a different setup:  I was running a WSL session, and my remote repository was GitLab not GitHub, but I had the same 'Command '' not found' message.

I tried several things with SSH and my agent (for example, I could push and pull from the command line), but I could not get VSCode to do repository push and pull operations through the GUI.  I noticed an indicator on my settings icon and it said there was a patch available.  I installed the latest VSCode and the problem went away.  Now on VSCode 1.65.2.